# How to fix datepicker resizing responsive problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, plugins

I'm setting up a new plugin datepicker in my laravel project

and want to fix responsive issue when resizing to mobile view

this is my customization codes that i select from  datepicker creator offer list in his site :

```
$(function() {
        $("#input1").persianDatepicker({

            theme: 'melon',
            alwaysShow: 1,
            cellWidth: 36,
            cellHeight: 20,
            fontSize: 15,
            calendarPosition: {
            x: 0,
            y: -93,
        },
        });  

});
```

and this is div structure that i put datepicker inside it :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container">


            <div class="row my-4 justify-content-center">


                <div class="col-xl-3">

                    <div class="card bg-light py-4 mb-3">

                        <div class="bg-light py-5">

                            <div class="py-5 bg-light">

                                <div id="input1"></div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card bg-primary py-4"></div>
                    <div class="card bg-primary py-4"></div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xl-9">

                </div>                                 
            </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

in laptop view i have picture below :

[image]

and in mobile view (iphone 6/7/8) i have picture below :

[image]

so i think you can understand what is my problem

the problem is when someone open my page in mobile the calendar went to left and i dont know

how to tell calendar box follow the parent div size and always fit and full size inside parent like

laptop view

#### For More Inforamtion This is Publisher of this plugin :

---

### [Datepicker](http://behzadi.github.io/persianDatepicker/)

Comment: Your pics aren't showing up?

Comment: Do you have width:100% on it?

Comment: on where please tell me exactly point ?

Comment: What element is the your calendar?

Comment: #input1 is your element that isn't stretching all the way across right?

Comment: yeah i want calendar (input1) stretch to its parent in all size

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
#input1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or you could do it like this:

```
 <div id="input1" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Put on you <div class="py-5 bg-light"> element. I don't know which one is your calendar. Inspect it like you did in the pic and find the element that isn't 100% width.

Comment: do you mean should i set width :100% to all div ?

Comment: You want to put it on the div that you want to be 100% across, not all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS.

```
// only apply style on mobile
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .pdp-default { 
    // Set calendar parent element to 100% width
    width: 100%;
    // Override inline left position set by plugin
    left: 0!important;
  }
  .pdp-default .cell {
     // set percent width of calendar date cells 7/100 = 14.28571428571429
     width: 14.28571428571429%!important;
     // Style calendar dates to stay at required aspect ratio
     height: 0!important;
     padding-bottom: 8%;
  }
}
```

Comment: something changed : in size iphone 5/SE the calendar stretch full size screen from the left and right ! not to parent div ... calendar stretch in width size and stick to the left and right screen

Comment: Add `position:relative;` to parent div.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed the plugin appends the HTML for the calendar before the end of the closing body tag. This means it is not actually inside your DIV structure, so you won't be able to achieve what you want with CSS. You are going to need to look in to getting the width of the parent element and applying it to the calendars parent element with your own javascript.

Comment: yeah exactly in the end of inspect i could see the html calendar but i didn't know what is this for and now you clear  ... tnx but i dont know javascript so what should i do ?

Comment: Sadly you will need to use javascript. The only other solution would be to have your parent div 100% width on mobile (which is pretty normal to do on mobile) and only apply the CSS I provided on mobile, so the calendar will default to it's normal size on tablet and desktop.

Comment: i remove your code from the css and add width : 100% to the html by javascript div (inspect mode) and something changed : calendar width stick to the right of screen ! but the left side was good and exactly was on parent border so even if i did this in javascript this will happen so what's next?

Comment: You would need to get the position of the parent div as well. However this is getting overly complicated for something that could be resolved by adjusting your layout on mobile. I don't think I can help any more because it is hard to give exact solutions without seeing a fucntioning version of your code, and I don't have the time to set up the plugin locally. Sorry.

Comment: yeah i know this but positioning just solve my problem in normal mode and in mobile view changed also the reason for the left side is exactly on the parent border is my position set ... ok thanks for guide me maybe someone else has time to help me because everything is ready to work on it i linked plugin address download ... Good Luck Bro